# Single empty cell with border at the end of the table when using phpExcel with mPDF

Tags: php, phpexcel, mpdf

I use mPDF to create pdfs from phpExcel. It's working great but for some mysterious reason I get a blank empty cell with border at the end of the table in the resulting pdf. The excel file without mPDF looks totally normal with no sign of any empty cells or borders there.

Not sure how to explain it further, but wondered if anyone has seen this before and know a solution to it? See image.

Edit// `$objWorksheet->getActiveSheet()->setShowGridlines(false);` seem to remove the border, but then I loose all the other row borders as well that I actually want.

[image: Empty cell with border]

Comment: Generic advice: Check for something stupid like a row with an empty cell at the end.

Comment: Doesn’t look like it. Is there a way to have border-bottoms with gridlines set to false?